# How to load ALL the columns from a *.csv into Neo4j nodes

Tags: csv, neo4j, load

Suppose I need to load a csv file c:\myData.csv

```
alfa,beta,gamma
0001,1000,thousant
0002,2000,two-K
...
```

in nodes

```
(:myData{alfa:0001,beta:1000,gamma'thousant'})
(:myData{alfa:0002,beta:2000,gamma'two-k'})
```

Is there a way to import ALL the columns into properties without specifying them one by one?

Something like

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/c:/myData.csv' AS line set line:myData create line
or
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/c:/myData.csv' AS line create (:myData {line.*})
```

Answer (score 5):

Following worked for me after trying different options, Neo4j 3.3.2:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///apples.csv' AS appleAllLineProperties
CREATE(apple:Apple)
set apple += appleAllLineProperties
```

Couple of observations:

1. CREATE(apple: {appleAllLineProperties}) results in error since Neo4j expects  *appleAllLineProperties* to be a parameter - which also isn't valid in this position.
2. Neo4j expects the file to be in the following folder

   C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Desktop\Application\neo4jDatabases\database-\installation-3.3.2\import

Comment: How to extract the names of the nodes instead of just id's.?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/c:/myData.csv' AS line 
create (:MyData {line})
```

or

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/c:/myData.csv' AS line 
MATCH (m:MyData {id:line.id})
SET m += {line}
```

Comment: This results in 
Expected a parameter named line
Neo.ClientError.Statement.ParameterMissing

Comment: remove the brackets around line for the second solution, for the first one use MERGE (n:MyData {id: line.id})
ON CREATE SET += line

Comment: @MichaelHunger please correct your first code block to read `... AS line CREATE (n:MyData) SET n += line` because this works, and your version gives the error Dirk mentioned.

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen You forgot `n` between `SET` and `+=`. I took clue from your comment and came up with the `CREATE` syntax in my last comment. The performance is way **way *way*** faster than `MERGE` when you don't have a schema index yet.

Comment: How to use this also while applying `IS NOT NULL` to every column to avoid null values.